# What instrument is used for measuring very low current / voltage?

Tags: measurement

I'm wondering whether galvanometer can be used or not ?

Comment: What do you mean by "low"? Is this dc, and if not, at what frequency?

Comment: One man's low is another man's high. For pA, you'd need a preamplifier before any mechanical instrument. For uA, you'd be OK with a galvo. For MA, a piece of iron hanging from a string in the general vicinity of the conductor would show a response.

Comment: @Neil_UK Under no circumstances short of the literally astronomical would anyone call MA-level currents "low", though.

Comment: @Hearth True, but it makes for an interesting image, doesn't it? Maybe it will help people pay attention to the difference between MA and mA.

Comment: Like everyone else is saying, what exactly is meant by "very low?"

Answer (score 1):

For low current, amplifying the voltage drop across a very precise and very small sense resistor is the usual approach. A commercially available and open source implementation of that technique is the [uCurrent](https://www.eevblog.com/ucurrentgold) produced by EEVBlog. It has a range switch for nA, uA, and mA.

Comment: I've been involved in measuring very low currents and, in the process, moved ***away*** from using trans-impedance (which uses a ***very*** high impedance feedback, not a *very precise and very small sense resistor*) to integration means, with capacitors. Best of all has been the use of ICs designed for this purpose (Burr Brown ACF2101, DDC112, etc.) In the case of small photocurrents, I was able to get down to noise levels where I could actually see boson flocking effects showing up just slightly above the Johnson and shot noise floors (low hundreds of aA -- below fA if aA is unfamiliar.)

Comment: @jonk you are right, transimpedance is based on a virtual ground usually,  not a sense resistance amplifier.